# Editor does not contain a main type

Tags: java, eclipse

Well I've done everything according to what our teacher has provided and what the book has to offer about this specific error. I've done everything correctly I believe but maybe someone on here can find the mistake.

```
public abstract class school {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        final int name = Nick;
        final int age = 19;
        final int school = Northeast Lakeview
        final int dogsname = Lord Hawooru

            final int steps = 4000

        final double miles = 1.757

        system.out.print ("Hello my name is" + name "and I am" + age "years old");
        system.out.print ( "I am enjoying the time I have spent so far at" + school);
        System.out.print ("Though I dearly miss my bundle of fun" + dogsname);
        System.out.print ("I am walking an average of" + steps "every day and that is equivalent to" + miles);
    }
}
```

Comment: you misplaced the tag javascript. Your code is messy. You did not put quotes around strings...

Comment: what's your issue in the question? Please reformat your code.

Comment: not likely to be an issue, but - capitalize your class names

Comment: This code is showing 8 different and fundamental problems in Eclipse. Without being cheeky, but I think you need to get a beginners guide to Java, and perhaps programming in general.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're using int types to enter string values.
2. You're using system instead of System. Classes and packages are case sensitive.
3. You're missing semicolons.
4. You've created an abstract class which can't be used standalone.
5. Eclipse probably tells you what's wrong anyway.

Comment: Not really, just giving you some advice.

Comment: So stating to someone about how they shouldn't be taken seriously on a subject they have never encountered before is your friendly way of giving advice? Terrible

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not compilable code, you will not get to the point where it tells you that a main method is missing. Please look through and fix your syntax errors. When you get to the point at which it compiles then start thinking about virtual classes and I think you will realize the important problem in your code.

If you still need help after that then edit your question and we will try to assist you further.

Comment: I've come to realize this, and thanks.